# Python: Selenium cann't finde the btn on pop-up window

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click the btn "select all cookies" on cookies terms pop-up window.
I'v tried:

```
div=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="js_cookie-settings-modal"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div')
driver.implicitly_wait(4)
button=div.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="selectAll"]')
driver.implicitly_wait(4)
button.click()
```

Error:

```
  raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.64)
```

Option2:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="selectAll"]'))).click()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
```

Error:

```
   raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

URL:https://www.eversports.de/

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: https://www.eversports.de/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use following **xpath** `//*[@id="selectAll"]'`, it is going to identify two elements, where first one is not **interactable**.

Use below **xpath** to **uniquely identify** the element.
You don't need to use **parent** element, you can use this **xpath** to identify and click on the button.

```
button=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[@id="selectAll" and text()="Accept all"]')
button.click()
```

---

Ideally you should use `WebDriverWait(`) to handle dynamic page element.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@id="selectAll" and text()="Accept all"]'))).click()
```

you need following imports.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

**Update:**

```
driver.get("https://www.eversports.de/")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@id="selectAll" and text()="Accept all"]'))).click()
```

---

It might possible `cookie` option will come for the first time and once accept it, it will never appear. Use try..except block to handle this.

```
driver.get("https://www.eversports.de/")
try:
     WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@id="selectAll" and text()="Accept all"]'))).click()
except:
     print("No popup found!")
     pass
```

Comment: I'v tried it but I got 

SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//button[@id="selectAll" and text()=Accept all"]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.64)

Comment: @ahm5, there was typo error. Please copy the latest one which I updated. `'//button[@id="selectAll" and text()="Accept all"]'`

Comment: Again:
   raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@id="selectAll" and text()="Accept all"]"}

Comment: Not sure still you are using the parent element. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Again:  WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@id="selectAll" and text()="Accept all"]'))).click()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @ahm5, If the pop-up won't appear then it will through the error? Are you sure pop-up appearing? When I run first time it worked without fail.

Comment: Use Try..except block to handle such issues. I have updated the code again.Please let me know the status.

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
No popup found!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252615/discussion-between-kunduk-and-ahm5).

Answer (score 0):

When you want to restrict the search inside an element using xpath, you have to add a `.` in front of the path, so you have to change the definition of `button` to

```
button = div.find_element(By.XPATH,'.//*[@id="selectAll"]')
```

Remember

- `//div` finds divs in all the html
- `.//div` finds divs which are descendants of the current node

Moreover

- `.//` finds the descendants of the current node
- `./`  finds the direct children of the current node

As a final note, the command `driver.implicitly_wait(4)` specifies the amount of time (4 seconds in this case) the the driver should wait when searching for an element if it is not immediately present in the HTML. If the element is found after 1 second then code execution will be continued without waiting for more 3 seconds, so if your intention was to pause the code for 4 seconds, then you should use `time.sleep(4)` instead. Also, `driver.implicitly_wait()` sets a global wait time, so
you don't have to place it before each driver command, it is enough to put it only once at the beginning or your code.